# openpyxl possible lambda usage

Tags: python, openpyxl

I was trying to assign value of a cell equal to sum of few other cell. I could achieve this using two line like

```
 dailycell=45
 while sheet['E' + str(dailycell)].value is not None:
                mysum+=sheet['E'+str(dailycell)].value
                sheet['B13']=mysum
                dailycell+=1
```

With my limited knowledge, I tried lambda. Then I get all sort of error. I tried few more iteration but none got me the same result.

```
sheet['B13']=lambda weeklybudget,sheet['E'+str(dailycell)].value:weeklybudget+=sheet['E'+str(dailycell)]
```

Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: There is no need ever to use lambda in Python. It can be useful sometimes but is never a must. You would be much better off breaking your code down into chunks that you understand better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just iterate over the whole `E` column and sum up the values:

```
sheet["B13"] = sum(c.value or 0 for c in sheet['E'])
```

If you have a restriction on what row to start from, then just grab the appropriate slice:

```
sheet["B13"] = sum(c.value or 0 for c in sheet['E'][46:])
```

If you need to stop summing at the first occurrence of `None`, you'll need a bit of external help - [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) comes to mind:

```
from itertools import takewhile

sheet["B13"] = sum(c.value for c in takewhile(lambda x: x.value is not None, sheet['E'][46:]))
```

Comment: I just realize the code you post is actually for the whole E column, I want to start at 45, I will edit my question, thanks for pointing out –

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, it would just continue iterating from 46 onward, but I want it to stop if it reaches a blank cell. I could not do that using slicing.

Comment: @Longroadahead - Yes, if you want it to stop at the first occurrence of `None` the things get a bit more complex, check the update...

Comment: Both gives an error,the takewhile gives an error :TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType' the other one gives ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple . Other than the error, I do want to understand this syntax more, is there a documentation on iteration?

Comment: @Longroadahead - Oops, I forgot that we're working with cells, check the last update. As for iteration, or rather generator expressions as above, you can start with [PEP 289](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).